# How can I have a png image with transparency, visible only from *front*?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, png, shader, transparency

I'm using a prefab for a box shape, which has a front and back *plane*.

My images are PNG and have transparent areas around the edge. I dragged the image onto my front plane, which now has a drop-down box for "Shader".

First I chose Shader: "Standard" but the transparent areas of my PNG image weren't transparent, so in order to fix that I changed it to "Sprites / Diffuse"... now the image looks fine (from the front).

However, when I rotate the shape, the image is also visible from the back. I want a way to *not* see the image / texture from the back.

How can I make the images *only* visible from the front side of a plane, whilst also preserving the transparency areas of the image / texture?

Comment: Show us the code of your shader so we can help you.

Comment: Could you show a picture of your shape? I'm guessing it has something to do with backface culling being off in your shader? Is it custom?

Comment: @AlexFerretti I used a box prefab which I found on unity answers for a different question. I can post a picture when I'm home tonight.

Comment: @DávidFlorek code of the shader, what do you mean by that? I just selected the shader from a list...

Comment: @vikingsteve in the case you make your own shader, you can tell him to render both side of a face by disabling backface culling in the code. So, depending on your shader, it might not have this culling enabled. Which one are you using?

Comment: @vikingsteve you said you adjusted the shader. Next time be more specific please.

Comment: You need a one-sided object (a plane) for this to work. It has literally *nothing* to do with the texture.

Comment: Everyone I updated the question, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Draco18s well when I look at my plane from the back side when the Shader is "Sprites/Diffuse" then it is visible. On the other hand if I chose Shader "Standard" then it is not visible from the back side... but then the transparent areas of my PNG look like junk.

Comment: The sprites/diffuse shader *specifically* forces the drawing of backfaces.

Comment: @Draco18s - thanks! You you suggest a way I can get transparency from my PNG images to work properly, without using the the sprites/diffuse shader? The transparent areas appear as grey with the standard shader...

Comment: @vikingsteve You have to set the material property "rendering mode" to "transparent." https://s12.postimg.org/rqzi5rw3h/material.png

Comment: @Draco18s would you like to add that as an answer and ill accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard built-in shader, you need to set the rendering mode to transparent in order for the texture's alpha channel to be transparent.  The sprite shader, by default, forces the rendering of otherwise invisible back-faces, whereas the standard shader does not.

[image: inspector dropdown]